# New repo or new folder in repo?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, cvs

So when it comes to re-writing a whole system do you prefer to make a new repo for the re-write or just a new folder in the existing repo?

The reason I ask is the new folder method requires some for though for the directory structure as you would need to start with some thing like.

```
/root
/root/v1/
```

Then add

```
/root/v2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the third option:

- rewrite the software in-place, without creating a new folder.

You use version control exactly so that you don't need to create folders per version.

To expand on the above a bit: if new system is radically different from the old system — a complete rewrite like you say — then I would probably use a new repository. If the rewrite is more incremental, then I would keep the existing repository.

Add a tag when you start the re-write or do the re-write on a **dedicated branch**, that way you can keep track of where the old code ends and where the new code starts. With a distributed version control system like Mercurial or Git, you could just create another **clone** on your server for the re-write.

Branches are a very powerful tool. I've written a [tutorial for Mercurial about branches](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/tasks/) that you might find interesting. There you see Alice and Bob working in parallel on several branches. In your case, you would still be able to add stuff to the old code while working on the new code.

Comment: It seems like it would be easy to lose where one starts and the other begins if you have a large amount of commits.

Comment: Create a version comment where you define the "this is the break really" - point.

Comment: Thanks in this case I'm more worried about complete re-writes as I have inherited very old projects that have to be re-written. I like the idea of multiple repo's for this because that enables me to keep the old repo around for minior updates that come up while building the new version. Branching though I think would handle this as well.

Comment: @hcker2000 Indeed, this seems a perfect candidate for branching. Just create your complete rewrite in a separate branch and don't merge with the main branch until everything works. At that point, you won't have a need for the old code anymore and you can merge the rewrite into the main branch.

Comment: I will definitely have to look into this. I have not used branching a whole lot. So you can still commit stuff to the old trunk while having a branch open?

Comment: @hcker2000: yes, you can keep working on both branches at the same time. You can ask the system to tell you what changes you've made since you started work on the branch. That will be useful if you make a change to the old code and you want to remember to make the same change to the new code. Propagating the change can normally be done automatically with a merge, but since you'll change everything,  you probably have to copy the changes by hand. This should not be a problem since you only make few changes to the old code.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a **new branch of the repository** if the new system is meant to be structured differently internally but that it interfaces with the rest of the system in the same way as the old version (e.g. the backend of a web application).

If it's both completely different internally and interfaces with the rest of the system in a different way than the old version, then I'd go with a *different repository* because it's more a new product than just a rewrite.